# Django - Editing Queryset in Views in order to pass to template

Tags: django, django-views, django-templates, django-queryset

I have a model named "groups" in a django project. In that model is a string field called "families". So I have many groups, each group has a field named "families". I need to turn this data into a queryset so that I may complete a string text replacement operation to send to my template. Below is the pseudocode.

teams = groups.objects.all() #Create a queryset for all groups - this works as hoped

editable_teams = teams.families #Call the specific field "families" within all "Groups" - this is not working

editable_teams.Replace('families', Value('Johnson'), Value('Jackson')) #I want to be able to do something like this - where I replace all instances of "Johnson" with "Jackson" inside each "families" field, for every instance of "groups".

Comment: Are you planning to edit the actual database values, or just to modify the in-memory data for use in a template? Also, it would be helpful if you show your model definitions.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
Group.objects.filter(name="Johnson").update(name="Jackson")
```